# Data scraping for specific jquery data from a website

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to fetch specific information from the `imageBlockVariations_feature_div` division of a page:

[image]

I tried the approaches below:

```
strval = doc.querySelectorAll(ID = "imageBlockVariations_feature_div").getAttribute("class")
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & rawno).Value = strval

strval = doc.getElementsByid("imageBlockVariations_feature_div").innerText
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & rawno).Value = strval

strval = doc.getElementsByid("imageBlockVariations_feature_div").getElementsByClassName("feature").Item(0).innerText
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & rawno).Value = strval
```

From all these attempts I got nothing.

Comment: I suggest you [edit] your question and use [markdow](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to format your code. I think that will make your code more readable and easier to understand which should help people to answer your question.

Comment: The method is not *getElement**s**ByID()*, it's *getElementByID()* Because there should be only one ID in the html document. What specific information do you need related to your example?